# Fetch exception from spark launcher thread

Tags: multithreading, apache-spark, exception

Is there a way to fetch the launcher exception from the launcher thread?

```
SparkLauncher launcher = new SparkLauncher()
                           .setSparkHome("sparkhome")
                           .setMaster("yarn-cluster")
                           .setAppResource("spark job jar file")
                           .setMainClass("spark job driver class")
                           .setAppName("appname")
                           .addAppArgs(argsArray)
                           .setVerbose(true)
                           .addSparkArg("--verbose");

SparkAppHandle handle = launcher.startApplication(new LauncherListener());
```

Need to get exception thrown by `launcher.startApplication()` method.

Note- Try catch block doesn't work as `launcher.startApplication()` method creates separate thread.